# Simple interactive testing

Tags: educational, learning

I need to create some sort of test for interactive board. I need the following functions:

At design time: objects with questions and answer (or answers), also some areas should play sound when clicked
[image: initial screen]

At test time:
Drag "question" over "answer area" to make answer. Also, after making decision, answer area should indicate if it is correct or not

[image: dragging questions]

Yet another thing I need is to join some questions and answers with arrows, also with correctness indication:

[image: connecting areas]